# Error with which() in R

Tags: r

```
minls<- -5.74
maxls<- 1.97
sseq<-seq(minls,maxls,0.5)
which(sseq==-0.24)
```

which(sseq==-0.24) gives output numeric(0)

To test
     sseq

```
 [1] -5.74 -5.24 -4.74 -4.24 -3.74 -3.24 -2.74 -2.24 -1.74 -1.24 -0.74 -0.24  0.26  0.76  1.26  1.76
```

As you can see the 12th element is -0.24

Simply creating an array by c(...) does not give this error

Is there something incorrect I am doing or is this a problem with the which() function, is there any alternative to which()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing numerical approximation issues.

try `sseq == -0.24` or `sseq+0.24`.

There you will notice that none of the values in `sseq` is exactly `-0.24`. So the problem has nothing to do with `which`, only with the fact that computers cannot represent all numbers exactly.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably due to floating point issue. You could use `all.equal` to check with a threshold (`tolerance` parameter of this function).

```
# tolerance is default - .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5
chk <- apply(as.matrix(sseq), 1, function(x) {
    ifelse(all.equal(x, -0.24) == "TRUE", TRUE, FALSE)
})
which(chk)
# [1] 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to @Arun answer, you can also do

```
# Change 1e-9 to whatever tolerance suits you best
which(abs(sseq-(-0.24)) < 1e-9)
```

Comment: aha.. clever.. I did `abs(seq)+0.24` and realised soon that it'll also give out positive values closer to 0.24. I had to change to `all.equal`. (+1).